# Creating list of cards of same height with flexbox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to do a list of card with the same width and same height.
I am using flex, bootstrap and some lines of adminlte.

My problem is that when some tags with text are bigger than others, the height of card change to fill the content and they becomes  with diferents heights.

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b5d8u06m/

markup
css

```
<style>
    .medicos {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
     }
    .medicos::after {
                content: "";
                flex: auto;
            }

    .item {
                flex: 1; 

     }

    .btn_hora {
                margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

[image: Sample of problem on fiddle]

Comment: add `display: inline-flex;` to `.item`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a vertical scrollbar and max-height.

---

Scrollbar: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

---

Height: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
.item {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.widget-user-2 .widget-user-header {
    padding: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    height: 150px;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```